# Alternate Stylesheets not working iOS5

Tags: ios5, css

I have a web site that uses alternate style sheets and has worked find with iPads using iOS4.  However this is not being called by iPad's running iOS5. I have also found that site http://css-tricks.com/examples/AlternateStyleSheets/ works fine on my iPad running iOS4 but not on my iPad running iOS5, indicating this is possibly a browser issue?

My site has the following snippets

```
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" id="smallScr" title="smallScr" type="text/css" href="/style/smallscreen.style.css" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" id="microScr" title="microScr" type="text/css" href="/style/microscreen.style.css" />
.
.
var varDevice = 'iPad';
alert('detected small (ipad) screen device = ' + screen.width + ' x ' + screen.height);
setActiveStyleSheet('smallScr');
```

In both cases the alert is called but my alternate sheet is not applied on the iPad running iOS5.

Has anyone come across this issue and have a solution

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. ios4 or any other browser, no problem swapping stylesheets, but ios5 wouldn't work at all. It would load the default stylesheet, then when it went to swap to the alternate no style sheets would be active. With some trial and error I got the following to work for me. Not totally efficient but it does seem to work.

Changing `$('link[rel*=stylesheet]').each` to `$('link').each`, and `this.disabled = false` to `$(this).attr( 'disabled', false );` seemed to make the difference.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" title="style" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css" title="style2" media="screen" />


var availableStylesheets = [ "style", "style2" ];

function stylesheetSwitch( styleName )
{
$('link').each( function() {
    var inStyles = false;
    for( var i=0; i < availableStylesheets.length; i++){
        if( $(this).attr('title') == availableStylesheets[i] ){
            inStyles = true;
        }
    }
    if(inStyles){
        $(this).attr( 'disabled', true );
        if ($(this).attr('title') == styleName) {
            $(this).attr( 'disabled', false );
        }
    }
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, looked at the specs and figured out a solution that seems to work in most browsers.

In your html head include the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Default-Style" content="">
```

Then to switch to one of your alternates from Javascript you can use per example:

```
document.querySelectorAll('meta[http-equiv=Default-Style]')[0].content = 'smallScr';
```